# Mshtml.h tutorial

Tags: c++, html

I am looking for  a c++ tutorial using Mshtml.h and IHtmlDocument ,it would be much appricated if someone could point me in the right direction.
Edit:I am trying to parse html

Comment: Please clarify. MSHTML provides lots of different functionality at lots of different levels of abstraction. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669236/mshtml-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317(v=vs.85).aspx

For editing tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770039(v=VS.85).aspx